# iAd banner positioning

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, iad

This code will position the iAd banner on the top of the screen. How can I position it so that it will locate at the bottom of the screen?

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

bannerView = ADBannerView(adType: .Banner)
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.hidden = true
    view.addSubview(bannerView)

    let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView": bannerView]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[bannerView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[bannerView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}
```

Comment: How exactly is this positioning your `ADBannerView` at the top of the view? What have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

Normaly these lines of code are enough to display a bottom banner ad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}
```

Apple takes care about the rest. If you are interested in a short tutorial: [Quick Tip: Integrate iAd banners in your iOS App with two lines of code](http://stefansdevplayground.blogspot.de/2015/07/quick-tip-integrate-iad-banner-ads-to.html)